# Can Eclipse suggest constructors for implementing types?

Tags: java, eclipse

I may be missing a trick here, but in Eclipse, if I do the following

```java
SomeInterface foo = new |
```

and hit `Ctrl-space`, I'm only given the option to produce an anonymous inner type. I'd love for Eclipse to present a list of constructors for the types that *implement* `SomeInterface`.

I'm happy to raise this as a wishlist bug for Eclipse, but I thought someone may know how to workaround this, or know of an existing bug (although I've failed to find one in my searches to date).

Comment: I'm not sure if you can fix that fully, but my eclipse install at least suggests implementing classes if I type the first character of it before pressing ctrl-space. I would have thought that'd be enough for most. If you don't know what implementations you have and want to list them you can use `open type hierarchy` (F4)

Comment: ctrl+T on interface will show implementations but not sure if eclipse does what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a bug against JDT/Text - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the correct product. New bug created: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385938.